# Debugger in geany

Tags: plugins, debugging, geany

I have problem with instaling debugger in geany
This is my problem:

```
> arwena@arwena-VirtualBox:~/geany-plugins/debugger$ make Making all in
> src make[1]: Entering directory
> '/home/arwena/geany-plugins/debugger/src'   CC      
> debugger_la-bptree.lo   CC       debugger_la-breakpoint.lo   CC      
> debugger_la-breakpoints.lo   CC       debugger_la-btnpanel.lo   CC    
> debugger_la-callbacks.lo   CC       debugger_la-calltip.lo   CC      
> debugger_la-dbm_gdb.lo   CC       debugger_la-dconfig.lo   CC      
> debugger_la-debug.lo debug.c:53:10: fatal error: vte/vte.h: No such
> file or directory  #include <vte/vte.h>
>           ^~~~~~~~~~~ compilation terminated. Makefile:1037: recipe for target 'debugger_la-debug.lo' failed make[1]: ***
> [debugger_la-debug.lo] Error 1 make[1]: Leaving directory
> '/home/arwena/geany-plugins/debugger/src' Makefile:587: recipe for
> target 'all-recursive' failed make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Can someone help me? I'm trying to do it for 4h, and really want to throw away my computer. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.3

Comment: No reason to toss your computer becuase of a missing dependency.  Just curious, but does `libvte-dev` exist on your system and have you installed it?

Comment: Yes, it's installed

Comment: This may be an issue in the plugins that didn't get in yet.  When you downloaded the plugins, did you pull a specific release or direct from git?  1.36.0 is the milestone in geany-plugins upstream a fix is scheduled for, but there's no ETA on it yet.  Note also: GTK2 is deprecated, GTK3 is the target, and this issue is long-standing since there's nothing forcing them to use GTK3 yet, and that may cause issues with the plugins actually working or not.  (I don't have a fix for you, just info I've found from googling sorry!)